# Update data table using shiny output in single code

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

I am Trying to create a shiny app which allows user to input values. The missing values in data will be replace by user provided value or default value. After user inputs the value, a new file is generate names data_new. I want to use this file to further update my raw data set to replace missing values. I am not sure how to take input from shiny app file and update data table.

Code Part 1:

```
library(shiny)
    library(readr)
    library(datasets)

data_set <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), B = c("3", "*", "*", "2"
), C = c("4", "5", "2", "*"), D = c("*", "9", "*", "4")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

    data_set1 <- data_set

    my.summary <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){
      result <- c(Mean=mean(x, na.rm=na.rm),
                  SD=sd(x, na.rm=na.rm),
                  Median=median(x, na.rm=na.rm),
                  Min=min(x, na.rm=na.rm),
                  Max=max(x, na.rm=na.rm), 
                  N=length(x),
                  Nmiss = sum(is.na(x)))
    }

    # identifying numeric columns
    ind <- sapply(data_set1, is.numeric)

    # applying the function to numeric columns only
    stats_d <- data.frame(t(data.frame(sapply(data_set1[, ind], my.summary) )))

    stats_d <- cbind(Row.Names = rownames(stats_d), stats_d)
    colnames(stats_d)[1] <- "variable"

    data_new <- stats_d
    #rownames(data) <- c()

    data_new["User_input"] <- data_new$Max
    data_new["OutlierCutoff"] <- 1

    data_new["Drop_Variable"] <- "No"

    shinyApp(
      ui <-
        fluidPage(
          titlePanel("Univariate Analysis"),

          # Create a new row for the table.
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                        choices = unique(data_new$variable), 
                        selected = unique(data_new$variable)[1]),
            numericInput("num", label = h3("Replace missing value with"), value = unique(data_new$variable)[1]),

            selectInput("select1", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                        choices = unique(data_new$variable), 
                        selected = unique(data_new$variable)[1]),
            numericInput("num1", label = h3("Outlier Cutoff"), value = unique(data_new$variable)[1],min = 0, max = 1),
            selectInput("select2", label = h3("Select any other Variable to drop"), 
                        choices = unique(data_new$variable), 
                        selected = unique(data_new$variable)[1]),
            selectInput("select3", label = h3("Yes/No"), 
                        choices = list("Yes", "No")),
            submitButton(text = "Apply Changes", icon = NULL)),
          mainPanel(

            dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
          ))  )  
          ,

      Server <- function(input, output) {

        # Filter data based on selections
        output$table <- renderDataTable({
          data_new$User_input[data_new$variable==input$select] <<- input$num
          data_new$OutlierCutoff[data_new$variable==input$select1] <<- input$num1
          data_new$Drop_Variable[data_new$variable==input$select2] <<- input$select3
          data_new
        })
      })
```

Code Part 2:

```
data_set[as.character(data_new$variable)] <- Map(function(x, y)
   replace(x, is.na(x), y), data_set[as.character(data_new$variable)], data_new$User_input)
data_setN <- data_set
```

Comment: You are not using a `data.table` object anywhere. Maybe you are thinking about the `dt` package and their DataTables (or however they refer to it).

Comment: This is a rather complex undertaking for what seems to be a first shiny program. It is not really structured the way it needs to be for a reactive program. Thinking about how to help you out with it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather complex undertaking, and where there is some cool code in there, you haven't really structured it in a way that you can make much forward progress in Shiny. It is probably way too complicated for a first or second Shiny undertaking.

I would rewrite it for you if I had the time, but I don't right now and I think you could do it yourself actually, and learn a lot. This is what I think has to be done:

**First** I would change the `submitButton` into an `actionButton`. In Shiny using the submitButton is almost always the wrong path to go down - it only leads to dead-ends (like the one you have now found). You need something like this:

```
  actionButton("applyChanges","Apply Changes"),
```

**Second**, you need to make the `data_new` into a `reactiveEvent` function. The calculation that you now do in the initialization has to be moved - or maybe copied - into the reactive code block. Something like this:

```
data_new <- eventReactive(applyChanges,{

  # code to change NAs in data_set1 to something specified in the input goes here
  ############################################################################### 

  ind <- sapply(data_set1, is.numeric)   
  stats_d <- data.frame(t(data.frame(sapply(data_set1[, ind], my.summary) )))
  stats_d <- cbind(Row.Names = rownames(stats_d), stats_d)
  colnames(stats_d)[1] <- "variable" 
  d_new <- stats_d
  d_new["User_input"] <- d_new$Max
  d_new["OutlierCutoff"] <- 1

  d_new["Drop_Variable"] <- "No"
  return(d_new)
})
```

**Third** I would convert all your input widgets into `renderUI` widgets and have them calculated in the server as well using that data_new reactive you just created.  Like this in the `ui` function:

```
   uiOutput("select")
```

And like this in the `server` function:

```
output$select <- renderUI({
      selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                  choices = unique(data_new()$variable), 
                  selected = unique(data_new()$variable)[1]),
    )
  })
```

Notice the function parens () in data_new(). This is because it is a reactive now. Do this for the input controls `select`, `num`, `select1`, `num1`, `select2`, `select3`.

**Fourth** (actually this might be good to do first), watch all the videos you can find by Joe Cheng on using Shiny - watch them as many times as you need to understand it. Reactive programming is different than other forms of programming. Takes awhile to get it.

Hope I didn't make any confusing syntax mistakes. Good luck with the restructuring. I don't think there is actually another way forward with Shiny, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed comments. I am still trying to implement above and come up with solution. Just a small question, how do we check/view the file d_new after return(d_new). I don't want the file in ui but want to check it in the global R environment. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Upvote and acceptance would be nice. Try "utils::View(mtcars)" to get a popup window with the current contents of a dataframe.

Comment: in ui   `actionButton("b1","View Mtcars")` and in server `observeEvent(input$b1,{utils::View(mtcars)})` will get you a popup with the mtcars dataframe for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to store the data table somewhere in my system. Is there a way to store the data in system and not just view it?

Comment: yes you could declare it as a reactive value inside the server code or actually one element of a reactive value since they are actually lists.

Comment: `reac1 <- reactiveValues(d_new= NULL)`. Then access it as reac1$d_new. You will still need that `eventReactive` though to supress shiny's constant attempt to keep everything up to date.

Comment: again this is an complex application to learn on and you are into the advanced stuff already. Try and get these things to work in a toy application first - you can post questions using the toy and get answers much much more quickly. Not everyone will take the time I did to understand a lot of code.

Comment: Yes, understood. Thanks. I will check reactive values.